# Getting error in pushing war files in Camunda Deployments

Tags: java, tomcat, gitlab-ci, war, camunda

I have configured the camunda platform on an EKS cluster and now I am trying to deploy my war files into my camunda deployment and I am REST API method for the deployment of war files into deployment. I am using GitLab, so I have written a script in my GitLab to deploy my war files but I am getting errors in it. I am adding my GitLab script and error here. I anybody has any idea about this process then please reply. I am stuck in this process for so long.

Script:

```
    #   SCRIPT=`realpath $0`
    #   SCRIPTPATH=`dirname $SCRIPT`

    #   if [ -z "$CAMUNDA_DEPLOYMENT_ENDPOINT" ]; then
    #     CAMUNDA_DEPLOYMENT_ENDPOINT="my_camunda_url/engine-rest/deployment/create"
    #   fi
    #   if [ -z "$CAMUNDA_DEPLOYMENT_NAME" ]; then 
    #     CAMUNDA_DEPLOYMENT_NAME="rest-deployment"
    #   fi
    #   if [ -z "$CREDENTIALS_USERNAME" ]; then
    #     echo "Error: Username not set, please set the CREDENTIALS_USERNAME env variable."
    #     exit 1;
    #   fi
    #   if [ -z "$CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD" ]; then
    #     echo "Error: Password not set, please set the CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD env variable."
    #     exit 1;
    #   fi
    #   ENCODED_CREDENTIALS=$(echo -n "$CREDENTIALS_USERNAME:$CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD" | base64)

    #   echo "Deploying to $CAMUNDA_DEPLOYMENT_ENDPOINT"

    #   CURL_OPTS="curl --show-error --fail -v -F upload="./target/Alert.war" --request POST --url $CAMUNDA_DEPLOYMENT_ENDPOINT --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data;' --form deployment-name=$CAMUNDA_DEPLOYMENT_NAME "

    #   echo "Executing deployment request:"
    #   echo "------------------------------"

    #   echo "RESPONSE:"
    #   echo "------------------------------"
    #   echo "$CURL_OPTS"
    #   response=$(eval "$CURL_OPTS")
    #   echo "------------------------------"
    #   echo "$response";
```

Error:

```
$ SCRIPT=`realpath $0` # collapsed multi-line command
Deploying to my_camunda_url/engine-rest/deployment/create
Executing deployment request:
------------------------------
RESPONSE:
------------------------------
curl --show-error --http0.9 --fail -v -F upload=./target/Alert.war --request POST --url my_camunda_url/engine-rest/deployment/create --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data;' --form deployment-name=rest-deployment 
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 13.235.39.166:80...
* Connected to my_camunda_url (13.235.39.166) port 80 (#0)
> POST /engine-rest/deployment/create HTTP/1.1
> Host: my_camunda_url
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 278
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------1e3495ddaf12e92b
> 
} [278 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
100   278    0     0  100   278      0   1355 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1356* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400 
< Date: Fri, 17 Jun 2022 06:49:54 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
* The requested URL returned error: 400
100   278    0     0  100   278      0    670 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   669
* Closing connection 0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 400
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deploy a complete WAR file via the Camunda API. Send BPMN,DMN or forms in your multi-part when creating a deployment
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/reference/rest/deployment/post-deployment/

If you need to deploy custom byte code, then you either need to include it in the build process (Camunda 7, e.g. JavaDelegate) or decouple it and let the task be performed using the external task pattern (C7 external task or C8)
(You may also want to take a look at: https://camunda.com/blog/2022/02/moving-from-embedded-to-remote-workflow-engines/)